# How to do field level @auth for bi-directional one-to-many @connection with AppSync GraphQL Transform?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying to figure out how can you protect at field level a one-to-many `@connection` with `@auth` against mutations that shouldn't be allowed. (ie: deny a specific user to run a mutation that will end-up inserting posts as another user.)

Starting with the example for protecting a mutation at the field level: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#field-level-authorization

I tried doing something like this:

```
type User @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "id" }]) {
  id: ID!
  posts: [Post]
    @connection(name: "UserPosts")
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "id" }])
}

type Post @model {
  title: String!
  user: User!
    @connection(name: "UserPosts")
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "userPostId" }])
}
```

Then say there already is a user with an id of `regular-user-id`
Apparently my auth rules don't stop another user, say with id of: `malicious-user-id` to run this mutation:

```
mutation {
  createPost(input:{
    title:"Oh this is BAD!"
    postUserId: "regular-user-id"
  }) {
    title
  }
}
```

Running a simple query to make sure this really happened:

```
query {
  getUser(id:"regular-user-id"){
    posts{
      items
      {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
=> 
{
  "data": {
    "getUser": {
      "posts": {
        "items": [
          {
            "title": "Regular User title"
          },
          {
            "title": "Oh this is BAD!"
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried various ways to figure this one out and couldn't find any documentation about bi-directional field level authentication. I'm fairly new to AppSync so I think I must be not getting something, but then this is such common use-case scenario that I'm really surprised there isn't more documentation about it.

Some help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To protect the `Mutation.createPost` mutation such that only the owner of the Post as designated via the `postUserId` may access it you add an @auth directive to the Post object definition:

```
type Post @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "postUserId" }]) {
  title: String!
  # This will use a field 'postUserId' by default.
  user: User!
    @connection(name: "UserPosts")
}
```

With this setup, a mutation:

```
mutation {
  createPost(input:{
    title:"Oh this is BAD!"
    postUserId: "regular-user-id"
  }) {
    title
  }
}
```

will fail if the logged in user is not "regular-user-id".

This answer may help fill things in as well https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1507#issuecomment-513042021.

Answer (score 1):

Should the malicious user be able to update the `Post` title? I know this isn't an exact answer to your question since you're focusing on the relation field, but from trying to understand how to do these kind of things myself, I read a few things about introducing some form of 'everyone' group so you can define auth for user's who aren't owners. Then you could put auth on the entire `Post` model so only owners can update any field;

```
type Post 
  @model 
  @auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, ownerField: "userPostId" },
    { allow: groups, groups: ["everyone"], operations: [read] }
  ]) {
  title: String!
  user: User!
    @connection(name: "UserPosts")
}
```

I'm super new to amplify (I'm currently evaluating whether to use it for a project I'm starting), so I could be completely wrong here. If you do actually want a semi-open model where just the reference field has auth, I'm not sure how to do that :(

Comment: It's not about updating once the post has been created. That works fine. Creating a post is where the problem lies. I couldn't find a way to prevent say UserB to run a mutation where he specifies the post belongs to another user say UserA.

Comment: The ownerField will be "postUserId" not "userPostId" that may be causing the confusion. You can also explicitly set the key fields using the "keyField" and "sortField" arguments on @connection.